Programmatically open WPF Popup control without losing Main Window focus
I have an UserControl that contains a ToggleButton and a Popup attached to it. Something like this:
<ToggleButton x:Name="TogglePopupButton"
              IsChecked={Binding ShowPopup}/>
<Popup x:Name="MyPopup"
       IsOpen={Binding ElementName="TogglePopupButton", Path="IsChecked"}>
    <!--Some code in here -->
</Popup>

My application monitors a few things and then set the ShowPopup property when something goes wrong and the message is shown in the pop-up.
When the ShowPopup property is set by some event handler, can we open the Popup control without having it focused? I would like to keep the focus on the Main Window.
I tried some ideas, like getting the popup window handle and use Windows API to show the popup window not-active and activate the main window, handle focus changed event, changing Focusable, etc., but without success...
I also try to handle the Main Window MouseEnter event to capture the focus. But while the popup is open the event is not triggered, only when I click, which is what I want to avoid.
Thanks

An alternative to a Popup, which is usually dismissed and / or gets in the way, is to use a "StatusBar". It's familiar and flexible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/statusbar?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

@GerrySchmitz indeed the StatusBar would be an option, but I will edit my question since I have to stick with the Popup. Interesting enough, I tried to handle the MouseEnter event of the Main Window, so it captures the focus, but the event is not triggered while the popup is open. I need to click on the main window, which is what I want to avoid.

A "popup" doesn't have to be a popup; it may only look like one. I have "tool boxes" (i.e. User controls) that "appear" and "disappear" (toggling visibility) when items are selected / deselected. I hang the UC's off a Window or other container (Canvas). In some case, I attach a "drag adapter" that lets the user move these "popups" around / out of the way. The UI is an illusion; there are no "rules" (IMO)

@GerrySchmitz You are correct. I can create something that looks like a popup. Regarding the "real" popup control, it creates a window internally and put it over the rest of the UI, preventing interaction with the parent without closing it first. Even when playing around with Win32 API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) the result was the same.
In the end I created a simple Popup using an Expander with a Canvas inside, due to the clipping. It accepts any number of children controls.

In the end I couldn't find a way of raising a Popup without focus. I think is due to the way the PopupSecurityHelper internal class handles the generated window.
I created a control that fit my needs. It's an Expander that contains a Canvas to bypass the boundary clipping and then be able to overlay other controls. The Z-index is something that I still need to figure out how to automatically set, since it depends on the container that the custom control is in. Just add the XAML to Themes.
Here is my first attempt:
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace PopupTest.Controls
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Children))]
    public class PopupExpander : Expander
    {
        private Expander _expander;
        private Canvas _canvas;
        private StackPanel _stackPanel;        

        public UIElementCollection Children
        {
            get => (UIElementCollection)GetValue(ChildrenProperty);
            set => SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Children),
                                                                                        typeof(UIElementCollection),
                                                                                        typeof(PopupExpander),
                                                                                        new PropertyMetadata());

        static PopupExpander()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(PopupExpander), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(PopupExpander)));
        }

        public PopupExpander()
        {
            Children = new UIElementCollection(this,this);
            Expanded += PopupExpander_Expanded;
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            _expander = Template.FindName("PART_Expander", this) as Expander;
            _canvas = Template.FindName("PART_Canvas", this) as Canvas;
            _stackPanel = Template.FindName("PART_StackPanel", this) as StackPanel;

            //Get first child and remove from list and add it to the Dock Panel
            //Do it until there is no child
            for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count;)
            {
                var child = Children[0];
                Children.RemoveAt(0);
                _stackPanel.Children.Add(child);
            }            

            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }     
      
        private void PopupExpander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ExpandDirection == ExpandDirection.Up)
            {
                Canvas.SetBottom(_stackPanel, 0);               
            }            
        }            
    }
}

XAML:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PopupTest.Controls">
    
    <Style TargetType="controls:PopupExpander">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:PopupExpander">
                    <Expander Name="PART_Expander"
                              IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                              ExpandDirection="{TemplateBinding ExpandDirection}"
                              Header="{TemplateBinding Header}">
                        <!--Add any TemplateBinding that we need-->
                        <Canvas Name="PART_Canvas">
                            <StackPanel Name="PART_StackPanel"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Expander>                        
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    
</ResourceDictionary>

